# How do I get the width of an svg element using d3js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using d3js to find the width of an svg element the code given below:

```
<script>
    var body = d3.select("body");
    console.log(body);
    var svg = body.select("svg");
    console.log(svg);
    console.log(svg.style("width"));
</script>

<svg class="svg" height="3300" width="2550">
   <image x="0" y="0" height="3300" width="2550" xlink:href="1.jpg"></image>
   <rect class="word" id="15" x="118" y="259" width="182" height="28"
      text="Substitute"></rect>
</svg>
```

But it returned this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null

I think, the svg variable is a null array.

How can I get the width of an svg element using d3js?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
<svg class="svg" height="3300" width="2550">
    <image x="0" y="0" height="3300" width="2550" xlink:href="1.jpg"></image>
    <rect class="word" id="15" x="118" y="259" width="182" height="28"
     text="Substitute"></rect>
</svg>

<script>
    var body = d3.select("body");
    console.log(body);
    var svg = body.select("svg");
    console.log(svg);
    console.log(svg.style("width"));
</script>
```

Just place your script after svg element is loaded by the browser and all will be fine.

Comment: Or execute it after page loaded.

Comment: svg.style("width") returns value with 'px' added which is not convenient.

Comment: You can always take 'px' away by using something like this: var widthString = svg.style("width"); var width = widthString.length > 2 ? Number( widthString.substring( 0, widthString.length - 2 ) ) : 0 ;

Comment: Or, more simply/faulty, parseInt(svg.style("width"))

Comment: Be careful using parseInt for this. If the SVG is styled using percentages then you won't get an accurate number by using parseInt (You will get 100 for a width of '100%')

Answer (score 17):

if you have an SVG element w/ id=frame...

```
 frame = d3.select('#frame')
                     .attr('class', 'frame')

            fh = frame.style("height").replace("px", "");
            fw = frame.style("width").replace("px", "");
```

fh and fw can now be used in math expressions.

you can also drop back to jQuery

```
  fw = console.log($("#frame").width());
  fh = console.log($("#frame").height());
```

which are numbers and can be used in math expressions

Answer (score 7):

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width",  "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%");

var w = parseInt(svg.style("width"), 10);
var h = parseInt(svg.style("height"), 10);
```

Comment: for less typing and also more speed you can do var h = +svg.style('height');

Answer (score 6):

You will end up with value "auto" unless you initialize the values of the attributes (width), I would recommend the below instead.

```
d3element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

or

```
var element = d3.select('.ClassName').node();
element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using svg.attr("width"). It just gives a plain number string.

Comment: This returns the string "100%" At least when using percentages.

Answer (score 2):

If this svg is saved in a variable, for example:

```
var vis = d3.select("#DivisionLabel").append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", height);
```

Then directly one can use the variable `vis` to get the width of svg by:

```
console.log(vis.style("width"));
```

The result is in unit "px". Pay attention that vis.style("width") returns a string.

Answer (score -1):

// HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <svg width="950" height="500"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//JavaScript

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');

const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');
console.log(width)
console.log(height)
```

At this days this is what work for me.